# How to get the results in a while loop in order to use it as a return in a function, c#

Tags: c#, function, if-statement, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to build a class with all my functions on it.

My function is trying to return my variable results which is a type TimeSpan. But I can't get the dataRecupere out of the condition in order to use it for my result.

Here is my code :

```
public TimeSpan differenceDate(string idAdmission)
        {
            TimeSpan resultat;
            TimeSpan dateRecupere;
            string requete = "SELECT AdmitDate FROM AdmissionRecords WHERE AdmissionID = @idAdmission";
            connexion.Open();

            SqlCommand commande = new SqlCommand(requete, connexion);
            commande.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idAdmission", idAdmission);
            SqlDataReader lecteur = commande.ExecuteReader();
            if (lecteur.HasRows)
            {
                lecteur.Read();
                dateRecupere = TimeSpan.Parse((lecteur["AdmitDate"]).ToString());

            }            
            connexion.Close();
            return resultat = dateRecupere - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        }
```

Comment: Just change `return resultat = ... ` to `return dateRecupere - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`

Comment: I tried it. My console is returning me an error which says that my locale variable isn't assigned from either resultat or dateRecupere!

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? Unrelated, but lookup the `using` keyword. If an exception is thrown in your code, you'll currently leave the database connection open.

Comment: The error would be 'Use of unassigned local variable 'dataRecupe''

Comment: @ChristopherNguyen - you can just delete the variable. The compiler is warning you about an unused variable because you are not using it. You don't need it, so just delete it.

Comment: It would still show the error even if I delete the variable result. I can't seem to get the dataRecupere out of my if

Comment: @ChristopherNguyen - Sorry, in my comment I mistook `dataRecupere` for `resultat`. I will add an answer and try to clean up the code.  Your actual question should probably be closed as it is just the result of a typo. You are now asking a new question, how to get rid of an unused variable warning. This also is something that results from a typo and would not be a good question for SO.  Nevertheless, I will provide an answer for you.

Comment: @pstrjds Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are assigning the result rather than returning it.  I will also clean up the code a bit and add some calls to `Dispose` since you are using objects which implement `IDisposable`.  In regards to unassigned variables, one thing that is recommended in C# design is to not declare variables until you need them.  In C you had to declare the variables at the top of the method, but in C# you don't.  Just declare them when needed.

```
public TimeSpan differenceDate(string idAdmission)
{
    // Declaring as a constant
    const string ReQuete = "SELECT AdmitDate FROM AdmissionRecords WHERE AdmissionID = @idAdmission";

    SqlCommand commande = null;
    try
    {
        connexion.Open();
        commande = new SqlCommand(ReQuete, connexion);

        // I am making the assumption that the AdmitDate is a Date field,
        // if it is a string, then just change this to string and check
        // for null before parsing it.  Note also that I am using the
        // ExecuteScalar method since you are running a scalar query.
        // This way you don't have to create a reader and have the
        // additional cleanup code associated with a reader
        DateTime? result = (DateTime?)commande.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result.HasValue)
        {
            return result.Value - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        }
        else
        {
            return TimeSpan.Zero; // I think this is probably what you would want as the default return value if there is no date
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // If an object implements IDisposable, you should call Dispose
        // or place it in a using statement
        commande?.Dispose(); // Newer C# syntax, old was if (commande != null)
        // we should be sure the connection is open before closing it
        if (connexion.State == Connection.Open) connexion.Close();
    }
}
```